# Is penalty success rate increasing over the time?

Tags: football, penalty-shot

As time goes by, the knowledge of football increases. And we learn more and more ( at least on paper) about [how to shoot penalty better](https://www.thestatszone.com/archive/statistical-insight-into-penalty-shootouts-where-to-place-your-penalty-13886).

Do the insights actually help football players in taking penalty? Does penalty success rate increase over time, much like how aviation accident is brought down over time? Or is it just an arm race with no side is apparently winning?

Any studies on the penalty success rate as a function of time?

Comment: I was tempted to change every occurrence of "penalty" in this post to "penalty kick", but I guess in soccer "penalty" is also equivalent to "penalty kick"?

Comment: @pacoverflow yes they are

Answer (score 6):

Considering [Transfermarkt](https://www.transfermarkt.de/premier-league/elfmeterstatistiken/wettbewerb/GB1/saison_id/1992) data on Premier League since 1992, I would say that the success rate has decreased over years.

```
Year | Success rate (%)
_______________________
1992 |  93.4
1993 |  97.6
1994 |  91.7
1995 |  94.5
1996 |  95.3
1997 |  93.4
1998 |  90.7
1999 |  97.1
2000 |  91.4
2001 |  90.4
2002 |  96.2
2003 |  95.7
2004 |  92.3
2005 |  77.0
2006 |  79.1
2007 |  78.2
2008 |  78.8
2009 |  78.9
2010 |  78.6
2011 |  74.2
2012 |  80.0
2013 |  83.9
2014 |  76.8
2015 |  81.3
2016 |  76.4
2017 |  70.0
2018 |  81.6
2019 |  80.6
```

[image: premier league]

For some reason, it drastically dropped between 2004 and 2005, and it was around 93% before and 78% lately.

---

[Transfermarkt](https://www.transfermarkt.de/1-bundesliga/elfmeterstatistiken/wettbewerb/L1/saison_id/1992) on Bundesliga since 1992:

```
Year | Success rate (%)
_______________________
1992 |  80.3
1993 |  84.7
1994 |  83.1
1995 |  79.2
1996 |  79.7
1997 |  73.2
1998 |  71.6
1999 |  75.8
2000 |  80.0
2001 |  72.5
2002 |  71.6
2003 |  77.6
2004 |  86.4
2005 |  73.1
2006 |  68.2
2007 |  78.0
2008 |  76.6
2009 |  78.2
2010 |  68.7
2011 |  86.8
2012 |  75.9
2013 |  73.6
2014 |  81.7
2015 |  79.1
2016 |  72.4
2017 |  73.1
2018 |  81.3
2019 |  78.1
```

[image: 1. bundesliga]

It's hard to find a pattern on the German statistics. They are roughly around 77%, with ups and downs equally distributed.

Comment: Interesting , any explanation why is it so ?

Comment: @Graviton I have no idea...

Comment: Someone has now [asked a question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/24354/15589) asking what caused the drop in success rate in the first graph.

Comment: @Bebs That's a great answer! Do you know how I can download the raw numbers (i.e. penalties taken vs penalties scored) for each of the years? Maybe even including the times they were taken...

Comment: @user2705196, I didn't find raw data. I just went to each page like the one I quoted.